# Line chart plotting multiple points for duplicate data on x and y axis using chart.js

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

i am a beginner working on angular8 application and using chart.js version ^2.9.3, i created a chart based on the below data.
Code Sample for creating Line chart with the data i have:

```js
    const labels = [65, 65, 80, 80, 56, 55, 40]
    const data = {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'My First Dataset',
        data: [67, 67, 81, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1
      }]
    };
```

i have picked up the sample line chart reference from the samples given on chartjs.org and modified the kind of duplicate data i get from my db.

I want to get a single point for duplicate x-axis and y-axis value rather than creating multiple points, how can i do that in Line chart?

I have attached the sample for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is manipulate your data beforehand by removing the duplicate values from your data array, the other option you can use is the object notation in combination with a linear x axis, this will still plot the point double but it will put it in the same place

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: 79,
        y: 80
      }, {
        x: 80,
        y: 81
      }, {
        x: 80,
        y: 81
      }, {
        x: 81,
        y: 77
      }],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      tension: 0.1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'linear'
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: hi LeeLenalee, thank you for taking out time but could you help me how can i do it with dynamic data binding to x, y coordinate, this was just an example with static data.

Comment: hi @LeeLenalee i want to bind data and labels as list of numbers rather than static data it would be dynamic list , could you help me with that.

Comment: Thanks @LeeLenalee, i got the reference and and i am able to do this in line chart, how can i achieve the same thing in bar chart any idea?